# Binary numbers in c program

Tags: binary

I'm trying to write a program that prompts the user to enter a positive integer N and prints the set of all binary strings of length N. For example, if the user enters 3, the program prints:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0
0 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

I have been trying this for a while but I was unable to do it. If someone can help me with this I will appreciate it!! Thanks

Comment: What in particular are you having trouble with?  Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a typical backtrack problem in algorithm, I made the  example code in C language here, you can have a reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getAllBi(int depth, int A[], int n) {
    if(depth >= n) {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            printf("%d ", A[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        return;
    }
    A[depth] = 0;
    getAllBi(depth+1, A, n);
    A[depth] = 1;
    getAllBi(depth+1, A, n);
}

int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *A = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    getAllBi(0, A, n);
    return 0;
}
```